# Improving json decoding with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

Can I improve that somehow?
i want to make it easier, maybe in loop couse in future i want to display more questions than only 10. I tried to use variable with string instead of  ,,idX" but it wasnt work.
I dont want use too much if statements

this is my json:
{"numberOfQuestions":2,"id1":{"id":"2"},"id2":{"id":"1"}}

```
 $.getJSON(apiUrl+'/api-V1/generateQuestions.php?category=math', function(data) {
                    numberOfQuestions =  data.numberOfQuestions;
                    questionIDs = new Array();
                    if(numberOfQuestions>=1){
                        questionIDs.push(data.id1.id);
                    }
                    if(numberOfQuestions>=2){
                        questionIDs.push(data.id2.id); 
                    }
                    if(numberOfQuestions>=3){
                        questionIDs.push(data.id3.id);  
                    }
                    if(numberOfQuestions>=4){
                        questionIDs.push(data.id4.id);  
                    }
                    if(numberOfQuestions>=5){
                        questionIDs.push(data.id5.id);  
                    }
                    if(numberOfQuestions>=6){
                        questionIDs.push(data.id6.id);  
                    }
                    if(numberOfQuestions>=7){
                        questionIDs.push(data.id7.id); 
                    }
                    if(numberOfQuestions>=8){
                        questionIDs.push(data.id8.id); 
                    }
                    if(numberOfQuestions>=9){
                        questionIDs.push(data.id9.id);  
                    }
                    if(numberOfQuestions>=10){
                        questionIDs.push(data.id10.id); 
                    }
                    loadQuestion(questionIDs[currentQuestion-1]);



                });
```

Comment: Please post some example `JSON` data that is returned from `ajax`

Comment: i dont quite get you code, for example if `numberOfQuestions == 10` you still onl push one questionId to your questionIds

Comment: Be a lot simpler if your questions were in an array rather than an object to start with. Would know how many just from length of array returned from server

Comment: If your code works as is, and you can make an example showing it working, and you are asking how to make it better, this question is off topic for Stack Overflow.  If this is the case, you should take the question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: json output: {"numberOfQuestions":2,"id1":{"id":"2"},"id2":{"id":"1"}}

Answer (score 2):

You might use a for loop and access the property using `id` and concatename the value of `i`:

```
for (let i = 1; i <= data.numberOfQuestions; i++) {
    questionIDs.push(data['id' + i].id);
}
```

```js
let questionIDs = [];
let data = {
  "numberOfQuestions": 2,
  "id1": {
    "id": "2"
  },
  "id2": {
    "id": "1"
  }
}
for (let i = 1; i <= data.numberOfQuestions; i++) {
  questionIDs.push(data['id' + i].id);
}
console.log(questionIDs);
```

Answer (score 1):

A `while` loop would be very concise here.

```
while(numberOfQuestions--) questionIDs.push(data['id' + (numberOfQuestions+1)].id);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can access values of an object using it's key in two ways:

1. the one you're using `object.key` in your example `data.id8.id`
2. the array-like way using `objec['key']` so `data['ind8'].id`

In the second way you use a string to access your value. So you could do sth. like:

```
numberOfQuestions =  data.numberOfQuestions;
questionIDs = []
questionIDs.push(data['id' + somenumber].id)
```

With this knowledge you can optimize the code.

```
for(let i = 1; numberOfQuestions >= i; i++){
    questionIDs.push(data['id' + i)].id);
}
```

Comment: loop condition is backwards